# How to add a + 1 to the number every time someone uses a command

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a bakery bot in discord.py where people are able to bake items, I'm making a command called "Cake", where users can run it every 2/1 minutes and their cake count will go up.

For example, if someone runs the command `b!bake cake` it would return "You've baked 1 more cake, you now have 2 cakes!"
How would I do this?

Comment: What code have you tried? Were there any errors or traceback? We would prefer if you gave us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you out better and faster, or at least some of the sources that you've already tried.

Comment: I've tried using increments, but I couldn't figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a the information somewhere.

If you want the data to be persistent across restart then write it to a file or database.

If you don't you can always save it to a variable accessible from anywhere. An option would be to use a global variable but it could be unaccessible from a cog, you can set an attribute in your bot's instance.

```
bot = commands.Bot(...)
bot.cakes = {}

@bot.command()
async def bake (ctx, dish):
    if dish == 'cake':
        if ctx.author.id not in bot.cakes.keys():
            bot.cakes[ctx.author.id] =  1
        else bot.cakes[ctx.author.id] += 1
        await ctx.send(f"you have baked {bot.cakes[ctx.author.id]} cakes")
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I'm going to use sqlite3 to store the data, would that work?

Comment: Totally. Just retrieve the info and store it in a variable, then use it and save it to the database again